# How do I prevent/delay a bunch of Bootstrap modules from loading their content right away to prevent slow site load times?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not a coder by trade but I find it really fun making and continually tinkering with my own website. I'm pretty happy with it but having so many hidden modules that slide up on click causes the whole site to not really function until they all load. Any suggestions for how I might keep them from loading until the main graphics load or suggestions/resources on what a better way to build this might be? Appreciate any help you might be able to provide!

http://www.ohkamp.com

Comment: This question will probably get closed as you've shown no code but here's a starter for ten - google "jquery imagesloaded" and go from there - that's not a complete solution but will help you understand what's causing your site to load slowly

Comment: Thank you. Sorry about that. I didn't know quite what code to show...

Answer (score 0):

If you have javascript modules, try to load them in the end of your html markup

e.g.

`<body>`

.....
......

`<script src="{your_script_file_path}"></script>`

`</body>`

Comment: Thanks! I think that will fix part of it. But the dozens of embedded videos are in the HTML. It's the loading of those embeds that are hidden from view that is creating hiccups. At least, I think so.